# How do I demolish a structure?

Tags: masters-of-the-arcane

After capturing an enemy city in Warlock: Masters of the Arcane, the city contains several buildings which I don't need but do cost me resources. How do I remove these buildings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Buildings can be shut down to avoid paying their maintenance cost, but the only way to get rid of them is to disband the entire city.

To shut down a building, go to the city view, then click on a building's icon, and it should grey out.

Comment: Weird, when I rightclick on a building, I can safely delete it. Was this an old version of MOTA?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the city view and click on the building you wish to destroy, if it is not needed for another building (foe example, farm for arrows chamber) then you can't click the icon (left, down in the little window) and voila - if you really want to destroy it then eliminate first the chamber of... and after that the farm (for example).